# Data Structure for Subsequence Queries

Tags: string, algorithm, search, data-structures, language-agnostic

In a program I need to efficiently answer queries of the following form:

> Given a set of strings `A` and a query string `q` return all `s ∈ A` such that q is a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of `s`

For example, given `A = {"abcdef", "aaaaaa", "ddca"}` and `q = "acd"` exactly `"abcdef"` should be returned.

---

The following is what I have considered considered so far:

1. For each possible character, make a sorted list of all string/locations where it appears. For querying interleave the lists of the involved characters, and scan through it looking for matches within string boundaries.

   This would probably be more efficient for words instead of characters, since the limited number of different characters will make the return lists very dense.
2. For each n-prefix `q` might have, store the list of all matching strings. `n` might realistically be close to 3. For query strings longer than that we brute force the initial list.

   This might speed things up a bit, but one could easily imagine some n-subsequences being present close to all strings in `A`, which means worst case is the same as just brute forcing the entire set.

---

Do you know of any data structures, algorithms or preprocessing tricks which might be helpful for performing the above task efficiently for large `A`s? (My `s`s will be around 100 characters)

---

**Update:** Some people have suggested using LCS to check if `q` is a subsequence of `s`. I just want to remind that this can be done using a simple function such as:

```
def isSub(q,s):
  i, j = 0, 0
  while i != len(q) and j != len(s):
    if q[i] == s[j]:
      i += 1
      j += 1
    else:
      j += 1
  return i == len(q)
```

**Update 2:** I've been asked to give more details on the nature of `q`, `A` and its elements. While I'd prefer something that works as generally as possible, I assume `A` will have length around 10^6 and will need to support insertion. The elements `s` will be shorter with an average length of 64. The queries `q` will only be 1 to 20 characters and be used for a live search, so the query "ab" will be sent just before the query "abc". Again, I'd much prefer the solution to use the above as little as possible.

**Update 3:** It has occurred to me, that a data-structure with `O(n^{1-epsilon})` lookups, would allow you to solve OVP / disprove the SETH conjecture. That is probably the reason for our suffering. The only options are then to disprove the conjecture, use approximation, or take advantage of the dataset. I imagine quadlets and tries would do the last in different settings.

Comment: If I input `de` would it still return `abcdef`?

Comment: Yes, I've added a link to Wikipedia for the precise definition of subsequence

Comment: Is there any other characteristic about `q` or the relationship between `q` and `s`? Like it's highly probable `q` contains adjacent characters of `s`, the length of `s` is in the same order of `q`, etc. If that's the case, you can take a look at the [algorithm for BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST#Algorithm). If not, I don't think there'd be useful preprocessing of `A`, since any substring of `s` has nothing to do with `q`.

Comment: @lcn Blast seems to find the substring of the target database that has the shortest edit distance to the query, so it would often give incorrect answers

Comment: @ThomasAhle, what I suggested was the preprocessing ideas BLAST uses, if your `q` contains some **substring** of `s`. It's not the goal of BLAST that matters.

Comment: @lcn Does it do other preprocessing than a three letter sequential word list?

Comment: This paper also looks very insteresting: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-38562-9_45 It's behind a paywall though

Comment: You still did not reveal if A or q is fixed or if both are variable. One of your comments below hints at A being relatively static and q variable. Would you please give a little bit more detail on this?

Comment: @UdoKlein It's a data structure, so we should support different queries, `q`. I don't think it matters if `A` is fixed or allows insertion/deletion, as there are common reductions that can transform a static data structure into a dynamic one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Tests

There have been four main proposals in this thread:

1. Shivam Kalra suggested creating an automaton based on all the strings in `A`. This approach has been tried slightly in the literature, normally under the name "Directed Acyclic Subsequence Graph" (DASG).
2. J Random Hacker suggested extending my 'prefix list' idea to all 'n choose 3' triplets in the query string, and merging them all using a heap.
3. In the note "Efficient Subsequence Search in Databases" Rohit Jain, Mukesh K. Mohania and Sunil Prabhakar suggest using a Trie structure with some optimizations and recursively search the tree for the query. They also have a suggestion similar to the triplet idea.
4. Finally there is the 'naive' approach, which wanghq suggested optimizing by storing an index for each element of `A`.

To get a better idea of what's worth putting continued effort into, I have implemented the above four approaches in Python and benchmarked them on two sets of data. The implementations could all be made a couple of magnitudes faster with a well done implementation in C or Java; and I haven't included the optimizations suggested for the 'trie' and 'naive' versions.

### Test 1

`A` consists of random paths from my filesystem. `q` are 100 random `[a-z]` strings of average length 7. As the alphabet is large (and Python is slow) I was only able to use duplets for method 3.

Construction times in seconds as a function of `A` size:
[image: Construction time]

Query times in seconds as a function of `A` size:
[image: Query time]

### Test 2

`A` consists of randomly sampled `[a-b]` strings of length 20. `q` are 100 random `[a-b]` strings of average length 7. As the alphabet is small we can use quadlets for method 3.

Construction times in seconds as a function of `A` size:
[image]

Query times in seconds as a function of `A` size:
[image]

## Conclusions

The double logarithmic plot is a bit hard to read, but from the data we can draw the following conclusions:

- Automatons are very fast at querying (constant time), however they are impossible to create and store for `|A| >= 256`. It might be possible that a closer analysis could yield a better time/memory balance, or some tricks applicable for the remaining methods.
- The dup-/trip-/quadlet method is about twice as fast as my trie implementation and four times as fast as the 'naive' implementation. I used only a linear amount of lists for the merge, instead of `n^3` as suggested by j_random_hacker. It might be possible to tune the method better, but in general it was disappointing.
- My trie implementation consistently does better than the naive approach by around a factor of two. By incorporating more preprocessing (like "where are the next 'c's in this subtree") or perhaps merging it with the triplet method, this seems like todays winner.
- If you can do with a magnitude less performance, the naive method does comparatively just fine for very little cost.

Answer (score 8):

It could done by building an `automaton`. You can start with `NFA` (nondeterministic finite automaton which is like an indeterministic directed graph) which allows edges labeled with an `epsilon` character, which means that during processing you can jump from one node to another without consuming any character. I'll try to reduce your `A`. Let's say you `A` is:

```
A = {'ab, 'bc'}
```

If you build `NFA` for `ab` string you should get something like this:

```
     +--(1)--+ 
  e  |  a|   |e
(S)--+--(2)--+--(F)
     |  b|   |
     +--(3)--+
```

Above drawing is not the best looking automaton. But there are a few points to consider:

1. `S` state is the starting state and `F` is the ending state.
2. If you are at `F` state it means your string qualifies as a subsequence.
3. The rule of propagating within an autmaton is that you can consume `e` (epsilon) to jump forward, therefore you can be at more then one state at each point in time. This is called `e` closure.

Now if given `b`, starting at state `S` I can jump one `epsilon`, reach `2`, and consume `b` and reach `3`. Now given `end` string I consume `epsilon` and reach `F`, thus `b` qualifies as a `sub-sequence` of `ab`. So does `a` or `ab` you can try yourself using above automata.

The good thing about `NFA` is that they have one start state and one final state. Two `NFA` could be easily connected using `epsilons`. There are various algorithms that could help you to convert `NFA` to `DFA`. `DFA` is a directed graph which can follow precise path given a character -- in particular, it is always in exactly one state at any point in time.  (For any NFA, there is a corresponding DFA whose states correspond to *sets of states* in the NFA.)

So, for `A = {'ab, 'bc'}`, we would need to build `NFA` for `ab` then `NFA` for `bc` then join the two `NFAs` and build the `DFA` of the entire big `NFA`.

### EDIT

NFA of subsequence of `abc` would be `a?b?c?`, so you can build your NFA as:

[image]

Now, consider the input `acd`. To query if `ab` is subsequence of `{'abc', 'acd'}`, you can use this NFA: `(a?b?c?)|(a?c?d)`. Once you have NFA you can convert it to DFA where each state will contain whether it is a subsequence of `abc` or `acd` or maybe both.

I used link below to make NFA graphic from regular expression:

http://hackingoff.com/images/re2nfa/2013-08-04_21-56-03_-0700-nfa.svg

### EDIT 2

You're right! In case if you've 10,000 unique characters in the `A`. By unique I mean A is something like this: `{'abc', 'def'}` i.e. intersection of each element of A is empty set. Then your DFA would be worst case in terms of states i.e. `2^10000`. But I'm not sure when would that be possible given that there can never be `10,000` unique characters. Even if you have 10,000 characters in A still there will be repetitions and that might reduce states alot since e-closure might eventually merge. I cannot really estimate how much it might reduce. But even having 10 million states, you will only consume less then 10 mb worth of space to construct a DFA. You can even use NFA and find e-closures at run-time but that would add to run-time complexity. You can search different papers on how large regex are converted to DFAs.

### EDIT 3

For regex `(a?b?c?)|(e?d?a?)|(a?b?m?)`

[image]

If you convert above NFA to DFA you get:

[image]

It actually lot less states then NFA.

Reference:
http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa

### EDIT 4

After fiddling with that website more. I found that worst case would be something like this A = {'aaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc' ....}. But even in this case states are lesser than NFA states.

Comment: What would you recon the complexity is for this? (once the dfa is build) Isn't it essentially just rewriting the query string `"abc"` as `a.*b.*c.*` and running it on every input?

Comment: Complexity would be number of characters in your input string or less. Since you are only propagating within directed graph consuming characters from input string. If there are `n` characters to consume your worst case complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: What if we build the NFA for `A={"abc"}`. That won't accept `"ac"` will it? Since the only paths from `(2)` are going to be `e` to `F` and `b` to `(3)`.

Comment: Yeah I wont include..should it include?

Comment: Yes, a subsequence of `"abcdef"` could be any of `""`, `"a"`, `"ab"`, `"ac"`, `"be"`, `"acf"`, `"cdf"`

Comment: Is it possible to extend your method for this case?

Comment: @ThomasAhle It possible to extend this method. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: This looks correct. However won't the dfa be exponential size?

Comment: Yeah it might grow large, but DFA is quite light weight data structure it just two-dim array mapping. And complexity of matching of characters is independent of size of DFA.

Comment: Right, but its difficult to store it if it is exponential in $|A|$ as that might be 2^1000000 or so. What do you estimate will be the size?

Comment: @ThomasAhle You're right! I put one more edit. Please take a look.

Comment: I still think the number of nodes will be very large. Have you tried to convert one of your NFAs into a DFA?

Comment: @ThomasAhle Please check this website http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa and try putting regex. I made a edit with one simple regex.

Comment: Nice, I still haven't been able to come up with a counter example, but can you give a proof that it won't explode?

Comment: @ThomasAhle It seems like worst case would be something like this: `(a?a?a?a?a?)|(b?b?b?b?b?)|(c?c?c?c?c?)`. But even in this case it lesser than NFA. I'm trying to find more formal proof.

Comment: Perhaps if DFA's really is the magic powder, it should be possible to extract an algorithm not described in terms of abstracts automa. Also as a side node, I tried to enter a random string of a?s and b?s and it became quite bigger than the NFA, though not too big

Comment: @ThomasAhle You mean algorithm for NFA to DFA?

Comment: I found this very interesting paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397591903589 It looks like it just might be what we've been looking for!

Comment: It is possible to run an NFA directly, without first converting it to a DFA. But it's O(_nm_) where _n_ is the input length and _m_ is the number of states in the NFA, whereas running a DFA is O(_m_) only, but for possibly much larger _m_.

Comment: This is the same article, but in a more detailed paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866703000297 It also proves that the standard NFA -> DFA construction will run with the same complexity as their more consise method. I will implement all the mentioned solutions and benchmark them before I choose the answer.

Comment: Oops, that paper only proved quadratic bounds for |A|=2. This paper proves that we get quite an explosion as |A| grows: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439750500157X . The size of the automaton is of the order `O(|s|^|A|/(|A|+1)^|A|*|A|!)`. Too bad, but let's still see how it works in practice

Answer (score 3):

As you point out, it might be that all strings in A contain q as a subsequence, in which case you can't hope to do better than O(|A|).  (That said, you might still be able to do better than the time taken to run [LCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) on (q, A[i]) for each string i in A, but I won't focus on that here.)

TTBOMK there are no magic, fast ways to answer this question (in the way that suffix trees are the magic, fast way to answer the corresponding question involving *substrings* instead of *subsequences*).  Nevertheless if you expect the set of answers for most queries to be small on average then it's worth looking at ways to speed up *these* queries (the ones yielding small-size answers).

I suggest filtering based on a generalisation of your heuristic (2): if some database sequence A[i] contains q as a subsequence, then it must also contain every subsequence of q.  (The reverse direction is not true unfortunately!)  So for some small k, e.g. 3 as you suggest, you can preprocess by building an array of lists telling you, for every length-k string s, the list of database sequences containing s as a subsequence.  I.e. c[s] will contain a list of the ID numbers of database sequences containing s as a subsequence.  Keep each list in numeric order to enable fast intersections later.

Now the basic idea (which we'll improve in a moment) for each query q is: **Find all k-sized subsequences of q, look up each in the array of lists c[], and intersect these lists to find the set of sequences in A that might possibly contain q as a subsequence.  Then for each possible sequence A[i] in this (hopefully small) intersection, perform an O(n^2) LCS calculation with q to see whether it really does contain q.**

A few observations:

1. The intersection of 2 sorted lists of size m and n can be found in O(m+n) time.  To find the intersection of r lists, perform r-1 pairwise intersections in any order.  Since taking intersections can only produce sets that are smaller or of the same size, time can be saved by intersecting the smallest pair of lists first, then the next smallest pair (this will necessarily include the result of the first operation), and so on.  In particular: sort lists in increasing size order, then always intersect the next list with the "current" intersection.

   - It is actually faster to find the intersection a different way, by adding the first element (sequence number) of each of the r lists into a heap data structure, then repeatedly pulling out the minimum value and replenishing the heap with the next value from the list that the most recent minimum came from.  This will produce a list of sequence numbers in nondecreasing order; any value that appears fewer than r times in a row can be discarded, since it cannot be a member of all r sets.
2. If a k-string s has only a few sequences in c[s], then it is in some sense *discriminating*.  For most datasets, not all k-strings will be equally discriminating, and this can be used to our advantage.  After preprocessing, consider throwing away all lists having more than some fixed number (or some fixed fraction of the total) of sequences, for 3 reasons:

   - They take a lot of space to store
   - They take a lot of time to intersect during query processing
   - Intersecting them will usually not shrink the overall intersection much
3. It is not necessary to consider *every* k-subsequence of q.  Although this will produce the smallest intersection, it involves merging (|q| choose k) lists, and it might well be possible to produce an intersection that is nearly as small using just a fraction of these k-subsequences.  E.g. you could limit yourself to trying all (or a few) k-substrings of q.  As a further filter, consider just those k-subsequences whose sequence lists in c[s] are below some value.  (Note: if your threshold is the same for every query, you might as well delete all such lists from the database instead, since this will have the same effect, and saves space.)

Comment: I like this idea. Do you have an idea about the length of the shortest string that contains all k-subsequences of s but not s?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: That depends.  If s = `aaaa` and k = 3, then `aaa` contains all k-subsequences of s.

Answer (score 2):

One thought; 
if q tends to be short, maybe reducing A and q to a set will help? 
So for the example, derive to { (a,b,c,d,e,f), (a), (a,c,d) }. Looking up possible candidates for any q should be faster than the original problem (that's a guess actually, not sure how exactly. maybe sort them and "group" similar ones in bloom filters?), then use bruteforce to weed out false positives. 

 If A strings are lengthy, you could make the characters unique based on their occurence, so that would be {(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1),(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6),(a1,c1,d1,d2)}. This is fine, because if you search for "ddca" you only want to match the second d to a second d. The size of your alphabet would go up (bad for bloom or bitmap style operations) and would be different ever time you get new A's, but the amount of false positives would go down.

Comment: This is basically the same idea as random_hacker?

Comment: In a sense, yes. We're proposing a to use a filter as step 1. Whether it makes sense to do this depends on some unknown parameters (amount of A's, size of the alphabet, lengths of the A's, length of q, amount of results per q, ...) The filtering mechanism is different though. I think overall his one will perform better then mine.

Answer (score 2):

First let me make sure my understanding/abstraction is correct. The following two requirements should be met:

1. if A is a subsequence of B, then all characters in A should appear in B.
2. for those characters in B, their positions should be in an ascending order.

Note that, a char in A might appear more than once in B.

To solve 1), a map/set can be used. The key is the character in string B, and the value doesn't matter. 
To solve 2), we need to maintain the position of each characters. Since a character might appear more than once, the position should be a collection.

So the structure is like:

```
Map<Character, List<Integer>)
e.g.
abcdefab
a: [0, 6]
b: [1, 7]
c: [2]
d: [3]
e: [4]
f: [5]
```

Once we have the structure, how to know if the characters are in the right order as they are in string `A`? If `B` is `acd`, we should check the `a` at position 0 (but not 6), `c` at position 2 and `d` at position 3.

The strategy here is to choose the position that's after and close to the previous chosen position. TreeSet is a good candidate for this operation.

```
public E higher(E e)
Returns the least element in this set strictly greater than the given element, or null if there is no such element.
```

The runtime complexity is O(s * (n1 + n2)*log(m))).

- s: number of strings in the set
- n1: number of chars in string (B)
- n2: number of chars in query string (A)
- m: number of duplicates in string (B), e.g. there are 5 `a`.

Below is the implementation with some test data.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SubsequenceStr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testSet = new String[] {
            "abcdefgh", //right one
            "adcefgh", //has all chars, but not the right order
            "bcdefh", //missing one char
            "", //empty
            "acdh",//exact match
            "acd",
            "acdehacdeh"
        };
        List<String> subseqenceStrs = subsequenceStrs(testSet, "acdh");
        for (String str : subseqenceStrs) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        //duplicates in query
        subseqenceStrs = subsequenceStrs(testSet, "aa");
        for (String str : subseqenceStrs) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        subseqenceStrs = subsequenceStrs(testSet, "aaa");
        for (String str : subseqenceStrs) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> subsequenceStrs(String[] strSet, String q) {
        System.out.println("find strings whose subsequence string is " + q);
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String str : strSet) {
            char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
            Map<Character, TreeSet<Integer>> charPositions = new HashMap<Character, TreeSet<Integer>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                TreeSet<Integer> positions = charPositions.get(chars[i]);
                if (positions == null) {
                    positions = new TreeSet<Integer>();
                    charPositions.put(chars[i], positions);
                }
                positions.add(i);
            }
            char[] qChars = q.toCharArray();
            int lowestPosition = -1;
            boolean isSubsequence = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < qChars.length; i++) {
                TreeSet<Integer> positions = charPositions.get(qChars[i]);
                if (positions == null || positions.size() == 0) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    Integer position = positions.higher(lowestPosition);
                    if (position == null) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        lowestPosition = position;
                        if (i == qChars.length - 1) {
                            isSubsequence = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isSubsequence) {
                results.add(str);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
find strings whose subsequence string is acdh
abcdefgh
acdh
acdehacdeh
find strings whose subsequence string is aa
acdehacdeh
find strings whose subsequence string is aaa
```

As always, I might be totally wrong :)

Comment: You're not wrong, it's just that you loop over strSet instead of preprocessing it. This way you can never get a better complexity that O(|street|) which is the goal.

Comment: Sorry, don't get your point. My preprocessing is to store the positions in a map. If you need to run multiple queries against the that strSet, the preprocessing only happens once.

Comment: I think you just speed up the individual checks "is q a sub sequence of s". If you run multiple queries you still need to run through a list of maps as big as strSet, no?

Comment: To clarify, while this is of course an optimisation, the problem is that the length of strings in the set is not the bottleneck, the size of the strSet is the bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look into the Book Algorithms on Strings and Sequences by Dan Gusfield. As it turns out part of it is available on the internet. You might also want to read Gusfield's [Introduction to Suffix Trees](http://webdiis.unizar.es/asignaturas/APD/suffixtrees.pdf). As it turns out this book covers many approaches for you kind of question. It is considered one of the standard publications in this field.

1. Get a fast [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm implementation. Actually it suffices to determine the length of the LCS. Notice that Gusman's book has very good algorithms and also points to more sources for such algorithms.
2. Return all `s ∈ A` with `length(LCS(s,q)) == length(q)`

Comment: Are  you sure you're not thinking of substrings instead of subsequences?

Comment: The book covers both and much more.

Comment: I read through the contents and didn't find anything sounding promising. Can you refer to the chapter covering this?

Comment: Theorem 12.5.3 The longest common subsequence problem can be solved in O(r Log n) time. 12.5.4 The lcs on more than two strings.

Comment: Depending on your problem at hand it may pay to actually work through the related chapters in order to understand how these algorithms work. Then you might be able to roll your own dedicated and much better (for your problem) algorith.

Comment: I know how to do lcs, but I don't see how it helps for this problem. If you can find a connection it would be very interesting, since the literature on that problem is vast.

Comment: I added more details in my answer. Hope this makes the connection clear.

Comment: It's very simple to check if a $s$ is a subsequence of $q$ in linear time. No need for an algorithm to do that. What is needed is a preprocessing that saves us from iterating through all of A

Comment: The link to the introduction to suffix trees is dead. I see several possible redirects, but I don't know which you want.